# How to convert SQL aggregate query into NHibernate Criteria Query

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm new to Criteria API in NHibernate. Can someone generate this piece of SQL using Criteria API in NHibernate?

```
select count(*) 
from result where Student_id 
in(
  SELECT s.Student_id 
  from Department as d
  JOIN Student s ON d.Dept_id=s.Dept_id
  where d.Dept_id=2
)
```

and how to proceed through the Criteria API in NHibernate. P.S I don't want to use HQL so without HQL is it possible to generate this kind of sql in nhibernate?

You can use linq-2-nhibernate as well.

Comment: Hey Joy. It would help if you put some extra effort in spelling/grammar/interpunction. If a question's easy to read you're more likely to get help. Additionally, it's usually appreciated if you try to work it out yourself first, and show us what you got so far before asking help. The [NHibernate documentation](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-criteria) may help you with this.

Comment: @jeroen well i have already seen that the problem is i can count based on single query but how to do that perticularly when the count is based on another subquery which i mentioned above.. i m not sure if i m proceeding right cause i didnt succed so i asked for help... sorry for bad english though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the following class structure:

```
public class Result{
    public virtual Student Student {get; set;}
}

public class Student{
    public virtual Department Department {get; set;}
    public virtual int Id { get; set;}
}

public virtual Department {
    public virtual int Id {get; set;}
    public virtual IList<Student> Students {get; set;}
}
```

Here is your query using the Criteria API:

```
var studentidquery = DetachedCriteria.For<Student>()
  .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Department.Id"),2)
  .SetProjection(Projections.Property("Id"));

var count = session.CreateCriteria<Result>()
   .Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("StudentId", studentidquery))
   .UniqueResult<int>();
```

Using the QueryOver API it would look like this:

```
var studentidquery = QueryOver.Of<Student>()
  .Where(x=>x.Department.Id==2)
  .Select(x=>x.Id);

var count = session.QueryOver<Result>()
   .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(x => x.Id).In(studentidquery)
   .Select(Projections.Count<Result>(r=>r.Id))
   .UniqueResult<int>();
```

Also I don't think you need the join to Department in your SQL query as you already have DepartmentId as a foreign key in the Student table. No sense in joining to extra tables for no good reason.

Comment: Exactly what i wanted .. i had those mapping sorry for not giving tht in question i thought just that would do . anyway one question over here ... we hit the database two times do we ? isnt it possible to generate the query at one go ? what i can see is it hits the database two times to get the job done :) i gues if the same can be done in one go itself ? :)

Comment: Those queries do not hit the DB two times.